# Is there a way to bind concisely on multiple events in Angular 2?

Tags: events, angular

Is there better way to bind on multiple events at once?
I know I can do

`<input (keyup)="callFunc()" (keydown)="callFunc()"/>`..

I wonder if there is a short hand like that:

```
<input (keyup,keydown)="callFunc()"/>
```

I tried and it didn't work..

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: There are not any documented at this time. I would probably file a feature request on the angular2 repo.

Comment: Thanks - will do :) I hope it is implemented at some point :)

Comment: Filed a request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Comment: From angular's official [declaring](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675), they don't have the plan to support it, but you can implement in this way with HostListener ```
       @HostListener('window:keydown.meta.s', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('window:keydown.control.s', ['$event'])
 onSavet(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  ...
 }
```, it should work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can implement this yourself through EventManagerPlugin.](https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/hacking-angular2-binding-multiple-dom-events-f781b14ef676#.1v9ydrcb0)

Also there is a [npm module which has this plugin already built](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-multievent-bindings-plugin/blob/master/README.md) that you can implement!!

`npm install angular2-multievent-bindings-plugin --save`

Comment: Great job :) I will definitely consider incorporating it :)