# how to neatly reference multiple angular event handlers to html elements

Tags: html, angular

I am very new to angular2 and i was wondering if there is a shorter way to write the `keypress` and `paste` events so that the html code will be more readable (i am using Type Script):

```
 <textarea rows="1" class="txt" (keypress)="c()" (paste)="c()" [(ngModel)]="LeftText"></textarea>
```

Comment: There's an interesting thread here on Github on this very topic https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983140/is-there-a-way-to-bind-concisely-on-multiple-events-in-angular-2  this one wasn't two day ago though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When HTML template becomes cluttered with Angular logic, this means that logic should be moved to directive/component classes.

In this case this can be a directive:

```
@Directive({  selector: '[modify]' })
class ModifyDirective  {
  @Input() modify;

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event.target'])
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event.target'])
  onModify(e) {
    if (this.modify) {
      this.modify(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Which is used like

```
<textarea [modify]="c">
```

Notice that `c` is passed to the directive as a callback, this means that a method should be bound to the context in order to keep proper `this`.