# Angular execute function two time on events in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a input field that is executing a function in two event on `(blur)` and another in `(keydown.enter)`, in both cases the function is saving the data in the server and switching the in put for a `<span>`, now the problem is that on `(keydown.enter)` in firefox the function is trigger ones but in chrome the function is trigger two times when i should be only ones.

**Template**

```
<input type="text" class="text-field"
  [(ngModel)]="column[item.id]" (blur)="setValue(nameInputDE, 'textDE', column)"
  (keydown.enter)="setValue(nameInputDE, 'textDE', column)"
  *ngIf="column.editModeNameDE && item.id == 'textDE'" #nameInputDE />
```

**Component.ts**

```
  public setValue(item, attr: string, col: KanbanColumn) {
    if (attr == 'myBoardColumnMapping' && item.id == col[attr]) {
      return;
    }
    this.log.trace('setValue(item: ' + item.id + ', attr: ' + attr + ', colID: ' + col.dataField + ')');

    let newVal;

    switch (attr) {
      case 'myBoardColumnMapping':
        col.myBoardColumnMapping = item.id;
        break;
      case 'text':
        col.text = item.value;
        break;
      case 'textDE':
        col.textDE = item.value;
        break;
      case 'wipLimit':
        col.wipLimit = item.value ? item.value : null;
        // if the value is invalid -> do not remove the input
        if (newVal < 1 || newVal > 100) {
          return;
        }
        break;
    }
    this.storeData(col);
  }
```

so far i have no idea how to fix this issue, firefox only take the first event on the input in this case `(keydown.enter)` but Chrome take both first `(keydown.enter)` and then `(blur)`executing the function two times, any idea how can i avoid this happen.

In the case of creating a directive that listen for the events, the result is the same, because in chrome both event are been triggered, chrome still executing the function two times.

Comment: You could consider utilizing RxJS operators such as [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)  and [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) to only execute an event if the inputs/arguments have changed.

Comment: Aren't you asking it to do it two times? What's in place to stop both blur and keydown events? This would be a good use case for RxJS like @AlexanderStaroselsky said

Comment: the idea is execute the function only ones no matter which event is trigger.

Comment: You will probably need to consider something like a custom directive that listens for both events at the same time. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387199/how-to-neatly-reference-multiple-angular-event-handlers-to-html-elements). Or as mentioned before, creating something like an RxJS Subject in combination with operators to filter out duplicate events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to neatly reference multiple angular event handlers to html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387199/how-to-neatly-reference-multiple-angular-event-handlers-to-html-elements)

Comment: Yeah in that case how to pass params to the function...?

Comment: You can use `@Input()` with [Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) to pass values/params.

Comment: i try the solution of the directive but still haven the same, the direct is listening for the events but because both event are been triggering in chrome, chrome still executing the function two time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a rough [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccmqkp) that can show you how to accomplish this using rxjs to listen to the keydown enter event and blur event while only taking the first one of either of those events.

You can experiment further with this by using more of the [filtering operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/).

The general logic is:

```
  const listenToKeydownAndBlur = merge(
    fromEvent(this.theInput.nativeElement, 'keydown').pipe(
      filter((ev: any) => {
        return ev.code === 'Enter';
      }),
      tap(ok => {
        this.submitType = 'keydown enter event';
        console.log('keydown enter');
      })
    ),
    fromEvent(this.theInput.nativeElement, 'blur').pipe(
      tap(ok => {
        this.submitType = 'blur event';
        console.log('blur');
      })
    )
  ).pipe(
    first(),
    tap(ok => {
      this.submitted = true
      // Do submit logic!
    })
  )

  listenToKeydownAndBlur.subscribe();
```

Comment: thanks so much the answer, it work good but in my case not completely, because other logic that is implemented on the input, but thanks.

Comment: Rxjs operators would still be the "better" solution regardless the other logic you have on the input.